# Different samples despite same seed in R

Tags: r, random-seed

I understand that setting the same seed using `set.seed()` should ensure the same result when using functions that use randomization, but it doesn't seem to work for me even with this simple example

```
set.seed(1)
a = 1:10
sample(a, 1)
sample(a, 1)
```

That is, I get two different numbers as outputs for the two `sample()` function calls.
What might be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the seed allows R to generate the same *series* of random numbers.  So when you call `sample()` for the second time, it's using the second number in that series.

If you want the same results from both calls to `sample()` you need to set the seed before each call:

```
    a = 1:10

    set.seed(1)
    sample(a, 1)

    set.seed(1)
    sample(a, 1)
```

See for example [how the random number generator works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65928/how-exactly-does-the-r-random-number-generator-work)